# Working Between Local, Dev and Production Machines / Servers

Tags: deployment, web, osx-mountain-lion

How do you as a Web Developer cope with working between Dev and Production servers and interms of config files etc?

What do you use etc

I am use to changing files manually etc

Comment: Use a distributed version control system, create a workflow through which only vetted changes are allowed to go to the production machines.

Comment: We're not (generally) web developers here perhaps you meant to ask this on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) and [Github](https://github.com/).

In addition, here is our set up:

1. Source Code: [Github](https://github.com/) / [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)
2. Dynamic Documents (Manuals, help, etc.): [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com)
3. Static Files (.PSD, .PDF): [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)
4. Task Management: [Asana](http://asana.com/)
5. Communication: [Skype](http://skype.com) / [Outlook.com](http://outlook.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Puppet from [link](https://puppetlabs.com/) which is very powerful software aiming at server config automations with lots of modules already available.

You can follow its tutorials and documentations available in product web site.